# Symfony 4.4 Error on FOSUserBundle : UserManager

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, fosuserbundle, vendor

I had a bug with symfony, I had to reinstall my vendor folder and since then I have a bug that I cannot fix.

`Argument 3 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in C:\wamp64\www\brouwers\var\cache\dev\ContainerMmxuCtr\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1664`

[Error on my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSh7e.png)

I have try to add : "doctrine/common":"^2.13" on my composer.json

The bug is still here ...

I don't know how to fix this.

Someone can help me ?

My composer.json

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^2.1",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "^3.0",
    "excelwebzone/recaptcha-bundle": "^1.5",
    "doctrine/common":"^2.13",
    "karser/karser-recaptcha3-bundle": "^0.1.8",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "^2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.2",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.4",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
    "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-pack": "*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.5",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
    "symfony/test-pack": "*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
```

}

Entity User :

```
<?php
// src/Entity/User.php
    
    namespace App\Entity;
    
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;
    
        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="2048k")
         * @Assert\Image(mimeTypesMessage="Please upload a valid image.")
         */
        protected $profilePictureFile;
    
        // for temporary storage
        private $tempProfilePicturePath;
    
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $profilePicturePath;
    
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // your own logic
            $this->roles = array('ROLE_ADMIN');
            $this->enabled = true;
        }
    
        public function getId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        /**
         * Asks whether the user is granted a particular role
         *
         * @return boolean
         */
        public function isGranted($role)
        {
            return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the file used for profile picture uploads
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         * @return object
         */
        public function setProfilePictureFile(UploadedFile $file = null) {
            // set the value of the holder
            $this->profilePictureFile       =   $file;
            // check if we have an old image path
            if (isset($this->profilePicturePath)) {
                // store the old name to delete after the update
                $this->tempProfilePicturePath = $this->profilePicturePath;
                $this->profilePicturePath = null;
            } else {
                $this->profilePicturePath = 'initial';
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the file used for profile picture uploads
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getProfilePictureFile() {
    
            return $this->profilePictureFile;
        }
    
        /**
         * Set profilePicturePath
         *
         * @param string $profilePicturePath
         * @return User
         */
        public function setProfilePicturePath($profilePicturePath)
        {
            $this->profilePicturePath = $profilePicturePath;
    
            return $this;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get profilePicturePath
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getProfilePicturePath()
        {
            return $this->profilePicturePath;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the absolute path of the profilePicturePath
         */
        public function getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() {
            return null === $this->profilePicturePath
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->profilePicturePath;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get root directory for file uploads
         *
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getUploadRootDir($type='profilePicture') {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../public/images/'.$this->getUploadDir($type);
        }
    
        /**
         * Specifies where in the /web directory profile pic uploads are stored
         *
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getUploadDir($type='profilePicture') {
            // the type param is to change these methods at a later date for more file uploads
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'profilePicture';
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the web path for the user
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getWebProfilePicturePath() {
    
            return '/'.$this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getProfilePicturePath();
        }
    
        /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function preUploadProfilePicture() {
            if (null !== $this->getProfilePictureFile()) {
                // a file was uploaded
                // generate a unique filename
                $filename = md5(random_bytes(10));
    
                $this->setProfilePicturePath($filename.'.'.$this->getProfilePictureFile()->guessExtension());
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * @ORM\PostPersist()
         * @ORM\PostUpdate()
         *
         * Upload the profile picture
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function uploadProfilePicture() {
            // check there is a profile pic to upload
            if ($this->getProfilePictureFile() === null) {
                return;
            }
            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->getProfilePictureFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->getProfilePicturePath());
    
            // check if we have an old image
            if (isset($this->tempProfilePicturePath) && file_exists($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath)) {
                // delete the old image
                unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->tempProfilePicturePath);
                // clear the temp image path
                $this->tempProfilePicturePath = null;
            }
            $this->profilePictureFile = null;
        }
    
        /**
         * @ORM\PostRemove()
         */
        public function removeProfilePictureFile()
        {
            if ($file = $this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath() && file_exists($this->getProfilePictureAbsolutePath())) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    
    
    
    }
```

fos_user.yaml

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: App\Entity\User
  from_email:
      address: "bastien@no.com"
      sender_name: "bastien@no.com"
```

Tks a lot

Comment: Looks like a bug that should be reported on https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle - the package might not be compatible with Doctrine v3 so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FOSUserBundle hasn't had a contribution since the 5th January as of today. We dropped it in our company, because it caused a lot of trouble with Symfony 4, since it isn't compatible with it as it seems.

The documentation from Symfony covers everything you need to know and do, so I'd start there and implement the authentication myself. Symfony 4 has pretty much everything built in what you need.

Here's a link to the official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/security/form_login_setup.html

The other way would to search for forks of the bundle that are compatible with Symfony 4 and use the fork or create one yourself.